# Sass Error while building a React + Typescript + Vite project for production

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, node-modules, vite

I was building my React Vite website using `npm run build` but it gave me this error:

```
error during build:
Error: expected "{".
  ╷
2 │     for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  │                   ^
  ╵
  stdin 2:19  root stylesheet
    at Object.wrapException (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1237:17)
    at SpanScanner.error$3$length$position (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:69418:15)
    at SpanScanner.expectChar$2$name (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:69500:12)
    at SpanScanner.expectChar$1 (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:69503:19)
    at ScssParser0.children$1 (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:93498:10)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_withChildren$1$3 (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:99936:39)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_withChildren$3 (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:99941:19)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_styleRule$2 (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:96998:20)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_declarationOrStyleRule$0 (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:96861:87)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_statement$1$root (/home/aditya/Documents/Programs/Web_Dev/React/TaskMate - Frontend/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:96749:166)
```

The website was running fine, and there were no error, plus this error is so random, it doesn't even point out to any of my code but an npm package inside node modules. This react website was frontend of a full stack app. I was building it using `npm run build` so that I could get my hands on final HTML JS and CSS files to serve from my backend. Would appreciate if there is any another way to get the HTML JS and CSS if the error isn't solved.

Also note that I am using `.sass` file extension instead of `.scss` and the code looks like this:

```
@tailwind base
@tailwind components
@tailwind utilities

$default-transition: all ease-in-out 250ms

#App 
    overflow-x: hidden

h1 
    @apply text-6xl font-extrabold

h2
    @apply text-5xl font-bold
```

do let me know if i am doing anything wrong, it was my first time using sass with tailwind and react

Also have my package.json in case you might need it:

```
{
  "name": "taskmate",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-ruby": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-inject": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

I tried deleting node modules and ran `npm i` wishing that freshly installed package might not have those errors but didn't work. I also removed sass from package.json and package.lock.json think that the error might be because of vite's inbuilt sass support must be clashing with the installed npm package and reinstalled node modules but this didn't work either.